# <v-radio> and <v-checkbox> components don't render on the page correctly (stage symbols appear)

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button, vuetify.js, radio-group

I have two Vuetify components `<v-radio>` and `<v-checkbox>`:

```
<v-radio-group 
    v-if="thisDessert.input_type == 'checkbox_single'"
>
    <v-radio
        disabled
        v-for="value in allValues"
        :key="value"
        :label="value"
    />
</v-radio-group>

<div
    flat
    v-else-if="thisDessert.input_type == 'checkbox_multiple'"
>
    <v-checkbox
        readonly
        v-for="value in allValues"
        :key="value"
        :label="value"
    />
</div>
```

NOTE: allValues represents an array e.g. something like ["Ve","We","Te"]

They work functionally, so if `thisDessert.input_type == 'checkbox_multiple'` then a `v-checkbox` is there to represent the correct values. However it looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to version, I tried to run it in codepen and radio/checkbox seems to be working.
https://codepen.io/manojkmishra/pen/dyYERzX

Template

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
  <v-radio-group >
  <v-radio disabled v-for="value in allValues" :key="value" :label="value"/>
  </v-radio-group>
  <div flat >
  <v-checkbox readonly v-for="value in allValues" :key="value" :label="value" />
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Script

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data () {
  return {
    allValues:["Ve","We","Te"]
  }
}
})
```